# Joining two tables with foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I am working on an attendance calculation page. I have two table...

manage_attendance

[image]

student_info

[image]

st_id is the primary key of student_info and also foreign key to manage_attendance...

I have to join both tables in order to show the attendance percentages of each student according to each subject and semester.

There is also a table subject where I get subject id according to semester.....

Please help me to do this.

I want exactly like this..

```
 rollno  st_name   st_id subject sum(status) count(status) avg(status)
```

If you want any clarification please ask.

My code....

```
$re=mysql_query("SELECT  `id` 
FROM  `subjects` 
WHERE  `sem_id` =  '1'");
while($ro=mysql_fetch_row($re)){

//selecting subject id...

$res=mysql_query("SELECT b.roll_no ,b.st_name,a.st_id, a.subject, SUM( 
a.STATUS ) , COUNT( 
a.STATUS ) , AVG( 
a.STATUS ) 
FROM  student_info b INNER JOIN manage_attendance a ON a.st_id=b.st_id 
WHERE a.sem_id =  '1'
AND  a.subject ='".$ro[0]."'
GROUP BY  a.st_id ");

//innerjoin code

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res)){
echo $row[0]."----|----".$row[1]."-----|----".$row[2]."-----|-----".$row[3]."-----|------".$row[4],"-----|-----".$row[5]."-----|------".$row[6];
echo"<br/>";
}


}
```

Is this correct?